# Why After upgrdating to Ubuntu 20.04, My filename including "fi" looks weird in File Manager?

Tags: icons, 20.04

It becomes a unicode icon like this:
[old name is config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHpZL.png)

How to check the problem where it comes from? 
I use zsh with zimfw.
Anybody could come to look at this?